# Unique data-binding

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I've got this issue involving data-bandings I can't seem to solve.

I'm guessing it might be the lack of my knowledge in the angular area.

If you know the solution I'd appreciate of you could include a small explanation as well.

**My issue:**

I've got a table that I use together with *ngFor to write up all users in my object of data.

I then have a collapse on each of these to make it possible for the user to edit each of these. Each of these collapses have their own "password" and "repeat password" fields.

Attached to the "password"-field I have a button that is called "Slump" what this button does is that it calls a function that changes a variable of type string to a random string that might want to be used as a password.

My issue is that when I call this function I changed the variable that I use as a data-binding in every row in the table. I want the generated password to be unique to the input-field it is attached to.

**Pictures**:

[image: Two collapsed table rows]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- separate
[image: Five none collapsed rows in the table]

**Code**:

**hantera-anvandare.ts:**

```
export class HanteraAnvandareCmp {
private updateUserPwd: string;

private users: Object[] = [
    { userID: '1',  firstName: 'Name0',  lastName: 'lastname', username: 'Name.lastname@companydomain.se', teamName: 'randomteamname',  teamID: 1 }, 
    { userID: '2',  firstName: 'Name2',  lastName: 'lastname', username: 'Name.lastname@companydomain.se2', teamName: 'randomteamname2', teamID: 2 },
    { userID: '3',  firstName: 'Name3',  lastName: 'lastname', username: 'Name.lastname@companydomain.se3', teamName: 'randomteamname3', teamID: 3 },
    { userID: '4',  firstName: 'Name4',  lastName: 'lastname', username: 'Name.lastname@companydomain.se4', teamName: 'randomteamname4', teamID: 4 },
    { userID: '5',  firstName: 'Name5',  lastName: 'lastname', username: 'Name.lastname@companydomain.se5', teamName: 'randomteamname4', teamID: 4 },
    { userID: '6',  firstName: 'Name6',  lastName: 'lastname', username: 'Name.lastname@companydomain.se6', teamName: 'randomteamname4', teamID: 4 },
    { userID: '7',  firstName: 'Name7',  lastName: 'lastname', username: 'Name.lastname@companydomain.se7', teamName: 'randomteamname4', teamID: 4 },
    { userID: '8',  firstName: 'Name8',  lastName: 'lastname', username: 'Name.lastname@companydomain.se', teamName: 'randomteamname4', teamID: 4 }
];
private teams: Object[] = [
    { teamName: 'randomteamname', teamID: 1 },
    { teamName: 'randomteamname2', teamID: 2 },
    { teamName: 'randomteamname3', teamID: 3 }
];

private generatePassword():string {
    var length = 8,
        charset = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789",
        retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    this.updateUserPwd = retVal;
}
```

**hantera-anvandare.html:**

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nytt lösenord</label>
        <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" ngControl="edit_password" [(ngModel)]="updateUserPwd" placeholder="Nytt lösenord">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <a (click)="generatePassword()" class="btn btn-primary">Slumpa</a>
              </span>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: At first I'd suggest you get rid of `$(event.target)` - especially the `$` (jQuery). jQuery won't ever find `[(ngModel)]` in the template. This is processed by Angular and never reaches the DOM.

Comment: I guess you need to provide more of your code to be able to provider a solution. Where is the element that has the id `password_slump'?

Comment: So whats the problem ? what is the current behavior? doesn't it generate unique password? or it generates an unique password but changes that updated password everywhere????

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah, sorry about that. I forgot to remove it. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Can you please explain a concrete example? Like - when I click the button `Slumpa` on xxx then yyy should be set to value zzz? What data is `*ngFor` iterating over. Can you please add the `*ngFor` line as well?

Comment: @micronyks The problem is that when I click the "slump"-button the new rendomed password is databinded to the variable updateUserPwd that is the used in every password-input. That means is shows up in every password-field as u can see in the picture.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I click slump, the randomed password shows in the field "password" beside the button. The same randomed password shows in the other password fields as well. That should not happen. The randomed password should ONLY show in the password-field beside the pressed slump-button :)

Comment: I need to see more code. The HTML in the question only has one `<input>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[working code](http://plnkr.co/edit/G3WeCUo5s7iNSQeN9PC6?p=preview)**

You have to create individual reference/different `ngModel` for each row that you iterate through with `ngFor` syntax.

(if I'm not worng) - You problem is when you update your password, it gets reflected in every row's password textbox. To avoid that you have to create different `ngModel` for each row as said above.

I have made this **[working code](http://plnkr.co/edit/G3WeCUo5s7iNSQeN9PC6?p=preview)** for you which does contain your code partially (not full code). I hope you will be able to fig out what I have done. you can have problem with `[(ngModel)]="updateUserPwd"`.

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for.

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group" *ngFor="#item of users;#i=index">
            <label>Nytt lösenord {{i}}</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="item.updateUserPwd" placeholder="Nytt lösenord">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <a (click)="generatePassword(i,item)" class="btn btn-primary">Slumpa</a>
                  </span>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>

private generatePassword(i,item):string {   <------this is single object from ngFor which you want to update.
    console.log('started' + i );
    console.log(item);
    var length = 8,
        charset = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789",
        retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }

    item.updateUserPwd=retVal;  <------ this is important. This will change/update individual object property that you want to update. 
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome @RamoMislimi ! Yes simple to understand.